# C++ OpenGL fstream issue

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I'm currently working on a project(c++), including the making of a log file containing some information collected throughout compilation and runtime using fstream. Upon using the glGetString() command, respectively with either GL_VENDOR/GL_VERSION/GL_RENDERER, the stream stops printing, hence having my log file stop at the point where I use either of these commands. Info is directly printed in the file throughout running. OpenGL version is up do date.

Edit:
A sample:
     buildLog.open ("Release/build.log");
     buildLog << "\nVendor: " << glGetString( GL_VENDOR );

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to be able to help with this problem. You need to provide code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Do you have a current GL context when you call `glGetString()`?

Comment: @genpfault Agh, it seems I've been trying to do this before the GL context. All works great now after posting it after. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glGetString()` requires (as do most OpenGL functions) a current GL context to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have not really learned OpenGL so this is a bit speculative, but I see that it returns a `GLubyte *`. Perhaps there was a casting problem. I would also try checking for fail/bad/eof to see if it reveals anything.

Comment: I'd suggested that e.g. glGet_String_(GL_VENDOR) would respectively return a string value.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, but the string should work, I would think. Using streams (like ostream) can also set the bad/fail/eof flags. In my experience, once one is set, no reading/writing file works, before you call clear(). (in this case, <name of fstream>.clear() )  As such, does calling clear after it help? Also, I would attempt checking for the flags, that is all that comes to mind. If none of this answers the question, I am not certain what your comment means. I take it to mean casting was not the issue.

Comment: Turns out it was the intention of calling this before the GL context itself. All sorted out now. Thank you!

Comment: I saw the comment about the valid GL context, but was not sure. It sounds like calling it without one returns a null pointer. My guess is that in the ostream overload of <<, a null pointer sets one of the flags somehow. Glad that it works for you, though.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it doesn't handle it. Thank you!